# Roots of unity near 1 in Z / p Z

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Let $r \ge 3$ be a fixed integer. I'm interested in primes p such that no integer in the interval $(-\sqrt{p}, \sqrt{p})$, except $1$ (and $-1$ if $r$ is even), is an r-th root of unity modulo p.

The naive heuristic that $r$-th roots of unity should be "randomly distributed" suggests that there should be infinitely many such primes, and indeed they should have density 1 among all primes. Can this be made rigorous?

Comment: Suppose $r=3$, so that we are looking at roots of $x^2+x+1$. Then this seems like it should follow immediately from results on uniform distribution of solutions to quadratic congruences mod $p$; see http://imrn.oxfordjournals.org/content/2000/14/719.abstract

Comment: Yes, it definitely does, and $r=4,r=6$ as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

OK, thinking a little more clearly about this... (hopefully)
Say $p\le N$ fails to have the property you want. Then $p | n^r-1$ for some 
$|n| < \sqrt{p} \le \sqrt{N}$. There are only $O(\sqrt{N})$ integers of the form $n^r-1$ with $n$ in this range, and each has only $O(\log{N})$ prime factors. 
So there are only $O(\sqrt{N} \log{N})$ exceptional primes $p \leq N$, which is tiny compared to $\pi(N)$.

Comment: Sweet! So this shows in fact that I could replace $(-\sqrt{p}, \sqrt{p})$ with any interval of the form $(-p^{\delta}, p^\delta)$ with $\delta < 1$ (which seems reasonable).